# Pyspark - Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe

Tags: pyspark, python-3.9

I am new to pyspark and just started with **pyspark** by following [this](https://www.kaggle.com/code/tientd95/advanced-pyspark-for-exploratory-data-analysis/notebook)

I have made the changes to the code basis on my local system. Below is the code how I am setting up pyspark

```
# Import PySpark related modules
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark
import os
import sys

os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = 'python'
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = 'jupyter'
from pyspark.rdd import RDD
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import functions
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, desc, col, size, array_contains\
, isnan, udf, hour, array_min, array_max, countDistinct
from pyspark.sql.types import *

MAX_MEMORY = '15G'
# Initialize a spark session.
conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]") \
        .set('spark.executor.heartbeatInterval', 10000) \
        .set('spark.network.timeout', 10000) \
        .set("spark.core.connection.ack.wait.timeout", "20000") \
        .set("spark.executor.memory", MAX_MEMORY) \
        .set("spark.driver.memory", MAX_MEMORY) \
        .set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", MAX_MEMORY) \
        .set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true") \
        .set("spark.memory.offHeap.enabled","true") \
        .set("spark.memory.offHeap.size","10g") \
        .set("spark.network.timeout", "300000")
def init_spark():
    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Pyspark guide") \
        .config(conf=conf) \
        .getOrCreate()
    return spark

spark = init_spark()
filename_data = 'endomondoHR.json'
# Load the main data set into pyspark data frame 
df = spark.read.json(filename_data, mode="DROPMALFORMED")
print('Data frame type: ' + str(type(df)))
```

While executing the code in cell

```
#  Helper function to calculate statistic(s) of the column name from a tuple x of (sport, records list of the column)
#, the stats to calculate is also given as an input
def calculate_stats(x,column_name, stat_list):
    sport, records_list = x
    stat_dict = {'sport': sport}
    if 'min' in stat_list:
        min_stat = min(records_list)
        stat_dict.update({'min ' + column_name : min_stat})
    if 'max' in stat_list:
        max_stat = max(records_list)
        stat_dict.update({'max ' + column_name: max_stat})
    if 'mean' in stat_list:
        average_stat = stats.mean(records_list)
        stat_dict.update({'mean ' + column_name: average_stat})
    if 'stdev' in stat_list:
        std_stat = stats.stdev(records_list)
        stat_dict.update({'stdev ' + column_name: std_stat})
    if '50th percentile' in stat_list:
        median_stat = stats.median(records_list)
        stat_dict.update({'50th percentile ' + column_name: median_stat})
    if '25th percentile' in stat_list:
        percentile_25th_stat = np.percentile(records_list, 25)
        stat_dict.update({'25th percentile ' + column_name: percentile_25th_stat})
    if '75th percentile' in stat_list:
        percentile_75th_stat = np.percentile(records_list, 75)
        stat_dict.update({'75th percentile ' + column_name: percentile_75th_stat})
    if '95th percentile' in stat_list:
        percentile_95th_stat = np.percentile(records_list, 95)
        stat_dict.update({'95th percentile ' + column_name: percentile_95th_stat})
    return stat_dict

def to_list(a):
    return a

def extend(a, b):
    a.extend(b)
    return a

def retrieve_array_column_stat_df(df, column_name, stat_list):
    # Convert sport & "column_name" to RDD to easily calculate the statistics of intervals by sports
    sport_record_rdd = df.select('sport', column_name).rdd \
    .map(tuple).combineByKey(to_list, extend, extend).persist()

    # Calculate statistics of the input column by calling calculate_stats function defined above
    record_statistic_df = pd.DataFrame(sport_record_rdd.map(
        lambda x: calculate_stats(x, column_name,stat_list)).collect()
                                      )
    # Set proper dataframe column orders
    columns_order = ['sport'] + [stat + ' ' + column_name for stat in stat_list]
    # Re order columns
    return record_statistic_df[columns_order]

stat_list = ['min', '25th percentile', 'mean', '50th percentile',
                     '75th percentile', '95th percentile', 'max', 'stdev']
interval_statistic_df = retrieve_array_column_stat_df(df, column_name='interval', stat_list=stat_list)
print('\nLet\'s look at statistic for interval, in seconds (by sport):' )
interval_statistic_df
```

I am getting below error

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\shiv\Desktop\test\pyspark_analysis_bigdata.ipynb Cell 45 in <cell line: 55>()
     51     return record_statistic_df[columns_order]
     53 stat_list = ['min', '25th percentile', 'mean', '50th percentile',
     54                      '75th percentile', '95th percentile', 'max', 'stdev']
---> 55 interval_statistic_df = retrieve_array_column_stat_df(df, column_name='interval', stat_list=stat_list)
     56 print('\nLet\'s look at statistic for interval, in seconds (by sport):' )
     57 interval_statistic_df

c:\Users\shiv\Desktop\test\pyspark_analysis_bigdata.ipynb Cell 45 in retrieve_array_column_stat_df(df, column_name, stat_list)
     41 sport_record_rdd = df.select('sport', column_name).rdd \
     42 .map(tuple).combineByKey(to_list, extend, extend).persist()
     44 # Calculate statistics of the input column by calling calculate_stats function defined above
---> 45 record_statistic_df = pd.DataFrame(sport_record_rdd.map(
     46     lambda x: calculate_stats(x, column_name,stat_list)).collect()
     47                                   )
     48 # Set proper dataframe column orders
     49 columns_order = ['sport'] + [stat + ' ' + column_name for stat in stat_list]

File c:\Users\shiv\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py:1197, in RDD.collect(self)
   1195 with SCCallSiteSync(self.context):
   1196     assert self.ctx._jvm is not None
-> 1197     sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
   1198 return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, self._jrdd_deserializer))

File c:\Users\shiv\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1321, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1315 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1316     self.command_header +\
   1317     args_command +\
   1318     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1320 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321 return_value = get_return_value(
   1322     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1324 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1325     temp_arg._detach()

File c:\Users\shiv\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py:190, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    188 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    189     try:
--> 190         return f(*a, **kw)
    191     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    192         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File c:\Users\shiv\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 155.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 5.0 in stage 155.0 (TID 1775) (shiv executor driver): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implWrite(NioSocketImpl.java:413)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.write(NioSocketImpl.java:433)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$2.write(NioSocketImpl.java:812)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketOutputStream.write(Socket.java:1120)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:125)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.implWrite(BufferedOutputStream.java:215)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:199)
    at java.base/java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:112)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:108)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.write$1(PythonRDD.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1(PythonRDD.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1$adapted(PythonRDD.scala:307)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2066)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:272)
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2672)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2608)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2860)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:952)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2228)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2249)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2268)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2293)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1021)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1020)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implWrite(NioSocketImpl.java:413)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.write(NioSocketImpl.java:433)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$2.write(NioSocketImpl.java:812)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketOutputStream.write(Socket.java:1120)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:125)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.implWrite(BufferedOutputStream.java:215)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:199)
    at java.base/java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:112)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:108)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.write$1(PythonRDD.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1(PythonRDD.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1$adapted(PythonRDD.scala:307)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2066)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:272)
```

I am not able to understand the error, can anybody help here?

Important info -

> pyspark and spark version - 3.3.1
> python version - 3.9.13
> Windows 11, 16GB,  Intel Core i5-11400H, NVIDIA-GeForce GTX 1650 with 4GB GDDR6 dedicated VRAM
> Java version - 19.0.2

I tried allocating maximum memory to driver and executors, increased heartbeat interval and network timeout and then later used findspark to intialize spark. The above code set up is the latest and still getting the same error.

**Update**

I tried running the code with the chunk of data and made the changes, the code ran successfully:

> df_min = df.limit(1000)

```
 stat_list = ['min', '25th percentile', 'mean', '50th percentile',
                         '75th percentile', '95th percentile', 'max', 'stdev']
    interval_statistic_df = retrieve_array_column_stat_df(df_min, column_name='interval', stat_list=stat_list)
    print('\nLet\'s look at statistic for interval, in seconds (by sport):' )
    interval_statistic_df
```

Therefore, the size of the data is the issue. Can anyone help me with the optimized code to omit the use of *rdd* and effectively use **map()** and **collect()**